# How I can list all added apps in javamelody monitoring using curl command?

Tags: java-melody

curl -vkg http://collectserver/ -H 'Authorization: Basic abc123==' -d "appName=APP_NAME&appUrls=http://myhost/myapp/"

This is working curl to add apps in javamelody monitoring

And I also tested for delete application
curl -v
"http://collectserver/collectServer?action=remove_application&application=$APP_NAME" -H 'Authorization: Basic abdvcgvh'

Now I want to create curl to list all added application using curl command plz help

Answer (score 0):

You can call the same URL with the parameters "?part=applications&format=json" or "?part=applications&format=xml"

You will get a map in json, which lists the applications as keys.

For example, curl -v "http://collectserver/collectServer?part=applications&format=json" -H 'Authorization: Basic abdvcgvh'